# How to move x-axis labels to the left using highcharts?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am using highcharts to create a nice chart. In my case I want to rotate the x-axis labels, but when I do so, the label on the right is not fully visible. Because of that, I want to position the labels more to the left. How can I do this?

I changed an online example so it is easy to play around; http://jsfiddle.net/6hw9tw8q/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
marginBottom: 80
},
xAxis: {
   categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'December'],
labels: {
  rotation: 45
},

},

series: [{
     data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
     }]
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
labels: {
  rotation: 45,
  x:-12
},
```

You can use x value to change position in x-asix [doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.x).
Here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hw9tw8q/2/).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a margin to the right side of the graph, this will mean that the text will not go outside the chart bounds.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    marginBottom: 80,
    marginRight: 40 //added this line
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'December'],
    labels: {
      rotation: 45,
    },

  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hw9tw8q/3/

**API on marginRight:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginRight

Answer (score 0):

I just found a better solution for my problem. I changed the rotation to minus 45 and this keeps the labels within the window...

http://jsfiddle.net/nxwkLr70/

```
labels: {
  rotation: -45
},
```